# Google Spreadsheet - get row and column in which function is executed

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I wonder if there is a method to get the row and column in which the function is being executed. For example in my spreadsheet, C5 is equal to expression : "=myFunction()".

```
function myFunction() {
   // get the row and column [ result : C5 ];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may give a try:

`var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();`

or get it through range, assuming range is 1x1 (you need to verify this using .getNumRows() & .getNumColumns() on range)

`var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();`

and use

`var a1Not = activeRange.getA1Notation();`

OR

```
var X = activeRange.getColumn() 
var Y = activeRange.getRow()
```

for use in absolute r[X]c[Y] notation and array handling.

RTFM - Read The Friendly Manual :)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range